# Flutter: AnimatedContainer change height while sliding

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using [Sliding Up Panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) package to use sliding panel. Sliding panel located above Scaffold's `bottomNavigationBar` and it has AnimatedContainer. Sliding panel has an `onPanelSlide` function witch indicates it state from 0.0 (closed / unexpended) to 1.0 (open / expanded). In gif below i have red sliding panel than on expanded set's AnimatedContainers height to 0 and to initial height at closed state. How can i make it change it height dynamically so it would set it height to 0 at the same time as sliding panel would fully open?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `Container` with height parameter set every `onPanelSlide` call

```
const NAV_BAR_HEIGHT = 100.0;

double height = NAV_BAR_HEIGHT;

onPanelSlide: (double position) {
   setState((){
      height = NAV_BAR_HEIGHT - position * NAV_BAR_HEIGHT;
   });
}

Container(
   height:height,
   child: MyNavBar(),
)
```

Comment: It kind of worked. Main problem is the nav bars height. I becomes much taller. I tried to change  NAV_BAR_HEIGHT to different values but it didn't worked

Comment: Try a [ConstrainedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html) maybe with a maxHeight constraint